# Different results for Watin Span when breakpoint is set

Tags: c#, watin

This is a snippet of the code that I am working on

```
if (!(strGCID.Substring(0, 3) == "BBP"))
{
    string strDate;

    Span spn = ie.Span(Find.ById("detail_page_section_1_section_b"));
    for (int x = 1; x < 12; x++)
    {
        strDate = spn.TableCells[x].Text;
        if (strDate.IndexOf("AM") > 0 || strDate.IndexOf("PM") > 0)
        {
            txtPurchaseDate.Text = DateTime.Parse(strDate).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, if I have a breakpoint set at the line that starts with "strDate = spn.Table" my program actually works the way it should and I find the data within a span block. If I remove the breakpoint I get an index error for the array where I try to step through the table cells looking for date. I have been staring at the code and can't figure out why this would be happening. At this point, I'm thinking that the easiest thing to do is not bother looking for the date on the page. The question is, what am I not seeing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to call WaitUntilExists...

```
Span spn = ie.Span(Find.ById("detail_page_section_1_section_b"));
spn.WaitUntilExists();
for (...
```

HTH!

Comment: OMG!!! THAT WAS IT!!! Geez. I had been staring at my code forever and forgot that I was skipping the preceding pages that would have normally led up to the one I was trying to read the cell from. I hadn't given it enough time to load. And with the debugger, since it was pausing, the page would have loaded while I was examining the code.

Comment: Glad to help!  As a rule of thumb, whenever I load up an element I always assert that it exists (spn.Exists in your case) before trying to use it.  Solved LOTS of unnecessary errors in my project!